# Converting 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy' format varchar to Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a requirement wherein I need to convert varchar column in 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy' format to date using sql server.

Is there any way to do so using cast or convert function in SQL Server or any other method.

EEE here refers to day of week, e.g Mon or Tue etc

Comment: Please show some sample data

Comment: What does `EEE` stand for?

Answer (score 2):

I still don't know what `EEE` stands for, so I've left it out of my answer.
Using Substring to break and re-arragne the string to a convertible format and a couple of convertsions to datetime and back to string, I came up with this solution.:

```
--                            'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy' 
DECLARE @String varchar(32) = 'EEE JAN 25 16:37:45 -02:00 2017'

SELECT  CONVERT(DateTime,
            CONVERT(datetimeoffset,
                CONVERT(char(19), 
                   CONVERT(DateTime, 
                       SUBSTRING(@String, 9, 3) + -- Day 
                       SUBSTRING(@String, 5, 4) + -- Month
                       SUBSTRING(@String, 28,4) + -- Year
                       SUBSTRING(@String, 11,9) -- Time
                   , 113) -- DateTime
                , 126) -- ISO8601   -- string representation of the datetime value in this format: yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm
              + SUBSTRING(@String, 21, 6) -- ISO8601 with time zone - yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ
            , 127) -- You can't convert directly to DateTime, you must first go though DateTimeOffset
        )-- Finally, A datetime value
```

Result:

```
25.01.2017 16:37:45
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester:](http://rextester.com/VWG2421)

Comment: This is the only answer so far that tries to actually deal with the specified format. +1.

Comment: EEE here refers to days of week. e.g 'Mon' or 'Tue' etc

Comment: Well, in this case it's safe to ignore.

Comment: After a lot of analysis I came to a conclusion that format specified in the question is not among the standard date time formats supported by SQL Server, hence it is not able to convert it to SQL date. Anyhow I got around the problem by passing the date string to Java and doing conversion in code itself or we can ignore EEE as answered above.

Comment: Of course it's not one of the standard formats, that's why I had to break and re-arrange it. Did you check my answer at all? I've even left a link to a demo on rextester....

Comment: The solution above as stated by you works, as it is a non standard time format, it will have to be broken and arranged. Thanks.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find this date format as a standard SQL Server date format so used the following:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(DateField, 9, 2) + ' '
    + SUBSTRING(DateField, 5, 3) + ' '
    + SUBSTRING(DateField, 27, 4) + ' '
    + SUBSTRING(DateField, 12, 8) AS DATETIME2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that actually worked well is the following. You may look into using a parameter for the month, 
You could use the 
`select DATEPART(MM,'january 01 2011')--returns 1` if you really want to look into it. 
But since I needed it to run for 2 months I did not bother... Or you could just run it 12 times and you're covered.

```
update table
SET
[date] = SUBSTRING(@String,26,4)+'-10-'+SUBSTRING(@String,9,11)
WHERE
[date] like '%Oct%'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111) AS [YYYY/MM/DD]
```

Comment: That does not answer the question.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score -1):

In SQL server you can use functions: `CAST()` and `CONVERT()`.  Where `CONVERT()` is more rich function and mostly used to get different styles of datetime data.

SQL Server:

```
 SELECT CAST('01-JAN-2009' AS DATETIME)
```

or you can use:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/JAN/2009') metod
```

in other database is special function `to_date()`